# Why can't a <form> element be a child of <tbody>?

Tags: html, html-table

The following HTML is invalid and a valid alternative is to put the form tags outside the table tags. My question is *why* it was decided to make it illegal.

```
 <table>
   <tbody>
     <form>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
     </form>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Why do you need a form tag inside a table?

Comment: Why should it be legal? The only logical thing to have inside of a table is a row or a section of a table. A form is neither of those things.

Comment: Because I am showing tabular data which contains runs of sequential data, and breaks between these consecutive items. I wanted to perform an action on these individual runs without splitting the table into separate tables.

Comment: @minitech - Why shouldn't it allowed? It makes sense to me in this instance.

Comment: This has perfect use. Imagine a table displaying a list of data, and the last row allows you to add to that list, with input fields. You want your input columns to match those of your list, without setting width manually.

Comment: `form` is not an invisible tag, it adds structure to the document, just like a `div` or any other element. How is a browser supposed to know how to render arbitrary elements *around* parts of a table?

Answer (score 6):

The tbody tag is used for grouping of table cells. It is not something that should contain any content, and therefore should not contain a form.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp

> The `<tbody>` tag is used to group the body content in an HTML table.
>
> The `<tbody>` element must have one or more `<tr>` tags inside.

You can put forms around the entire contents of the table or inside of a single table cell.

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to consider using `<div>`s with CSS styling instead of tables. Tables are intended for presentation of data (not form input). Whereas divs are meant more for sectioning and designing.

Comment: Another w3schools link * shudders * :'( A better link would have been https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: @jammykam: When it becomes the first result on Google, that is what I will click on. And regardless of what the cliche here is, it is still a relevant and useful source of information.

Comment: I know, but it's back links like this that make it the top result. Instead we (collectively) should link to better references. It's the 2nd result in Google, you don't have to look far.

Comment: I realise that this is how TBODY is defined, my question was *why* is it defined like this? Why not allow a form to contain a few rows? It certainly makes sense to me in this instance.

Comment: @tom you can! Ok, here's a slightly different question: a table can have multiple `tbody` elements, why can't I wrap each `tbody` in a form? I don't see why, semantically, that should be an issue.

Comment: @aidan: Because the people in charge of creating the standards for the web defined it as such. You are not the first person to ask this question and there a many ways to handle this. Doing a quick Google search will return ways for you to work around this. But it appears that this post is more about a ranting.

Comment: @tom: Sorry if it comes across as a rant. I believe there are legitimate reasons for it to be allowed (which I've outlined above). And so the fact that it's not allowed prompted me to ask the question *why*. "That's how it's defined", while correct, is not an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer is purely speculation.*

**Allowing Non-Table Elements Would Unnecessarily Complicate Rendering**

At some point during the creation of HTML it was apparently deemed necessary a way to present tabular data. Now we would want this to be some what simple and standardized to prevent overly complicated rendering algorithms that would result in a variety of bugs. Try to think of the rendering of a table from a developer perspective. How hard would it be for you to write code that renders data within any of the given restraints under normal conditions. Now add to that, the possibility of any other type of element being intermixed with those table elements. This considerably complicates how we must calculate the rendering.