# I can´t add an Excel button to my table and my form is not working when using DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I'm using DataTables library  from https://datatables.net/ and I want to have an Excel Button to download all the table, but everything I'm trying is not working:

I tried adding

```
 buttons: [ {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        autoFilter: true,
        sheetName: 'Exported data'
    } ]
```

Or

```
buttons: [
    'excel'
]
```

Or

```
buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Save current page',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'current'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

And this is my DataTable Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            autoFilter: true,
            sheetName: 'Exported data'
        }],
        order: [[3, 'desc']],
}
```

But doesn't work.

I know my Js works because it's not the only customization I'm doing, so I don't know where I'm wrong.

And my form whas working fine but when I added `DataTable` is stopped working don't know why. Just that, what it suppose to send the value from the button to another View, but it doesn't work now and only added the Library, I didn't touch code behind

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover text-center" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column1</th>
                                <th>Column2</th>
                                <th>Column3</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tbData">                            
                             <form action="~/Home/ReadOption" method="post">
                                <input hidden value="entrega" name="seleccion"/>
                                @{
                                    string delivery = "";                                    
                                }
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        if (entrega != item.DeliveryNumber)
                                        {
                                          <tr>
                                              <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="@item.NumeroEntrega"  name="identi">@item.DeliveryNumber</button></td>
                                              <td>@item.TaskNumber</td>
                                              <td>@item.RandomNumber</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        }

                                        delivery = item.DeliveryNumber;
                                    }                                
                           </form>
                        </tbody>                    
                </table>
```

Comment: a `<form>` inside`<tbody>` is not valid html: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056218/why-cant-a-form-element-be-a-child-of-tbody

Comment: try to wrap the table inside the form, as in `<form><table>.....</table></form>`

Comment: Buttons won't be displayed for your DataTable until you include the `B` needed for [the `dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) - for example `dom: 'Brftip'`. And you need [the Buttons libraries](https://datatables.net/download/index) as well, of course. I don't see the `dom` option in your table definition. And you have not shown us what libraries you are using.

Comment: But before using Datatebles it was working...but okey

Answer (score 0):

As @GrafiCode told me, to fix the form, I put it outside the `<table>`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover text-center" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column1</th>
                                <th>Column2</th>
                                <th>Column3</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tbData">                            
                             <form action="~/Home/ReadOption" method="post">
                                <input hidden value="entrega" name="seleccion"/>
                                @{
                                    string delivery = "";                                    
                                }
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        if (entrega != item.DeliveryNumber)
                                        {
                                          <tr>
                                              <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="@item.NumeroEntrega"  name="identi">@item.DeliveryNumber</button></td>
                                              <td>@item.TaskNumber</td>
                                              <td>@item.RandomNumber</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        }

                                        delivery = item.DeliveryNumber;
                                    }                                
                           </form>
                        </tbody>                    
                </table>
```

And also for Button of the atatable, I read the documentation and concluded I was missing something for the DOM so this is the final dataTable code:

```
 dom: "Blfrtip",
        buttons: {
            dom: {
                button: {
                    className: 'btn'
                }
            },
            buttons: [{
                    extend: "excel",
                    text: 'Exportar Excel',
                    className: 'btn btn-primary',
                    excelStyles: {
                        template:'header_blue'
                    }
                }                
            ]
        }
```